# Best way to use react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react we can use 3 different way to create a component.

1.`const App =()=>{...}`

2. `const App = React.createClass({...})`

3.`class App extends React.Component{...}`

Which the best solution to define a component?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Reza! This question is primarily opinion-based, so it doesn't really lend itself to this forum. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This may give you some more information https://www.andreasreiterer.at/react-functional-components/

Comment: Each way has its use-case, there's no "best"

Comment: Generally, #1 - the functional component, is used for less complex components that don't do much more than render and fire event handlers passed to them as `props`. The do not have an instance. So they can't have `refs` and don't have the component lifecycle the way #2 and #3 do. #2 is kind of the old-school way of creating a fully instantiated `Component` class. #3 is what you see people using more lately. But they're basically the same thing in different clothing. #1 really is different. Which is "best"? -- Yeah, that part is opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the use-case and preference.
See https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components for why you would like 1 over 3 or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It Depends on what you'r going to do with your component.

If you want states in your components then use `class App extends React.Component{...}`

If you want stateless components means just work with some props and return some JSX  than use  `const App =()=>{...}`

Using stateless components is consider as good practise.